# Auto-copying values from adjacent cells to non-adjacent cells in excel

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8lKt.jpg)I need to make an auto-fill of values from adjacent cells in table to another non adjacent cells of another table, for example, I need to get the following:

Source values: C7,C8,C9 ...
Destination: G4, G7, G10 ...

[image]

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about your use case for this. I also have questions:

Are the source and destination always ordered? Meaning the names appear in the same order in both? Are these both on the same sheet as in your example? Are there always 3 cells per name in the destination?

I can't think of a formula that would give the desired result, but here's an approach I would take.

1. Make sure your source values and destination are on separate sheets.
2. Create a helper column in your source value range numbering your rows of data 1...x
3. Copy cells 1...X and paste them directly below you last row of data two times. So you should see 1...X repeat twice.
4. Sort your helped column least to greatest - you should now have two empty rows between each row of data.
5. Copy the column of data you need and paste into your destination. Because of the empty rows it should preserve your spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with VLOOKUP. Use this formula in the *Destination* table.

```
=VLOOKUP(G3,Source,2,FALSE)
```

- *G3* is the cell in which the name, e.g. "Mike", is written. In your sample this appears to be a merged cell. Note that in merged areas all cell content is always in the first cell. So, if G3:G5 are merged, nothing can be retrieved from G4 or G5 because all content is in G3.
- *Source* is a named range of 3 rows and 2 columns, as per your example. If your source is a true table you can use its name. VLOOKUP requires that the name must be in the first column of the range you specify. You can also specify a hard range, if you don't like using names. In my example the `Source` range was $A$4:$B$6.
- *2* is the column in `Source` from which to return the result.
- *False* specifies that you don't want an approximate match (but an exact one).

Of course, this method works in the direction opposite to your diagram. The formula is in H3 in my test sheet. This is because there are no formulas in Excel that write to cells they don't themselves occupy.